# Проверка на наличие в [,] массиве

Tags: c#

Есть переменная, допустим `string s = "/87536464"`, необходимо проверить её на наличие в первом столбце `[,]` массива и в случае, если такого значения там нет, то записать.

Как подобное делается ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD**:
Совсем туго с проф. языком, попробую объяснить иначе:

Я получаю данные в одномерный массив, затем переписываю их в двумерный массив (в первый столбец), потом получаю еще одномерный массив и мне надо продолжить запись в двумерный массив только тех значения из одномерного массива, которых ещё нет в двумерном.

Вот как раз значение `"/87536464"` одно из значений одномерного массива.

Я присваиваю переменной это значение эначение `string s = "/87536464"` и вот эту мать её переменную мне надо проверить на наличие в двумерном массиве.

И если она там есть, получить ответ `true` если её там нет `false` - вот и всё.

**UPD**
Вот как из массива `Ssilki[]` получить в массив 'Baza[]' только те значения, которых нет в 'Baza[]' , т.е. не дублировать одни и те же.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp7
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] Ssilki = new string[5];

            Ssilki[0] = "1000";
            Ssilki[1] = "2000";
            Ssilki[2] = "3000";
            Ssilki[3] = "4000";
            Ssilki[4] = "5000";

            string[,] Baza = new string[100, 20];

            Baza[0, 0] = "1000";
            Baza[1, 0] = "3000";

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Добавьте примеры проверяемых строк и ожидаемые результаты их проверки

Comment: @Андрей я добавил пример и поправил описание.

Comment: @Vipz имелось ввиду примеры кода =)

Comment: Я так понимаю нужно проверить каждый первый элемент строки в двумерном массиве?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Т.к. постановка вопроса не совсем понятная, я сделал простой вариант когда есть массив строк и массив дополнительных строк, нужно в первый добавить только те строки второго массива которые в первом не встречаются. Использовал HashSet для того чтобы алгоритм был быстрый для случая когда много строк, если строк мало и скорость не важна можно проверять и через `List.Contains` или просто циклом.

Вот моё решение на C#, [можно запустить онлайн](https://repl.it/NUBW/0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class CheckStrings
{
    static void Main() 
    {
        string[] strs = {"ab", "cd"};
        string[] to_add = {"cd", "ef"};

        HashSet<string> checker = new HashSet<string>();
        foreach (string s in strs) checker.Add(s);

        List<string> strs_list = new List<string>(strs);

        foreach (string s in to_add) {
            if (!checker.Contains(s)) {
                strs_list.Add(s);
                checker.Add(s);
            }
        }

        strs = strs_list.ToArray();

        foreach (string s in strs) Console.Write(s + " ");
    }
}
```

Дополнение: вроде уточнились с постановкой задачи, код выше я переписал для двумерного массива, вот что получилось, [можно запустить онлайн](https://repl.it/NUt3/0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class CheckStrings
{
    static void Main() 
    {
        string[,] strs = {
          {"ab", null},
          {"cd", null},
          {null, null},
          {null, null},
        };
        int n = 2; // Initial number of strings in strs.
        string[] to_add = {"cd", "ef"};

        HashSet<string> checker = new HashSet<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) checker.Add(strs[i, 0]);

        foreach (string s in to_add) {
            if (!checker.Contains(s)) {
                strs[n, 0] = s;
                checker.Add(s);
                ++n;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) Console.Write(strs[i, 0] + " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Судя по тому, что получается в онлайн примере, вы правильно меня поняли. Т.e у Вас "ef" записывается, как раз потому, что он не встретился. Но как это всё перекинуть на двумерный массив xD

Comment: @Vipz В случае двумерного массива если нужно скажем в 0-м столбце проверять и добавлять, то нужно просто итерировать и проверять элементы `strs[i, 0]`, т.е. вместо foreach использовать обычны for с индексом `i`. Также как понял по примеру у вас в двумерном массиве уже выделено достаточно места для всех дополнительных строк, это означает что не нужно как в моём примере временно копировать в List для добавления, а просто устанавливать на первое свободное место новый элемент. Вообщем сейчас просто дополню свой ответ для двумерного случая.

Comment: @Vipz да я что то опух совсем xD Не могу разобраться, перепробовал все предложенные варианты и не получается собрать то, что нужно.

Comment: @Vipz Ну вот дополнил ответ вторым кодом, при этом `n` это число строк сколько было в исходном двумерном массиве, потом с добавлением новых уникальных строк `n` растёт. Кстати я расчитываю что массив имеет достаточно мест под новые строки, т.к. в C# массив не может менять свой размер после создания, потому если нужно дополнять массив в конец т.е. чтобы он рос то нужно создавать новый, а промежуточные варианты хранить в List как в первом примере.

Comment: Блин, огонь ! - Это работает без танцев. Пытался другие примеры прижить и понять, что то не удавалось Массив больше чем нужен.

Answer (score 1):

Вот, обход каждого первого элемента строки двумерного массива с заменой если не соответствует: (Изменен)

```
bool ContainsValue(string arg, string[,] mas)
{       
    bool res = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < mas.GetLength(0); i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < mas.GetLength(1); j++)
            if (mas[i, j].Equals(arg))
            {
                res = true;
                break;
            }

    return res;
}

bool ContainsFirstColumn(string arg, string[,] mas)
{
    bool res = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < mas.GetLength(0); i++)
        if (mas[i, 0].Equals(arg))
        {
            res = true;
            break;
        }

    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
bool SetString(string[,] array, string str, int index)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
      if (array[i,index] != null)
      {
         if (array[i,index] == str)
            return false;
      }
      else
      {
         array[i,index] = str;
         return true;
      }
   return false;
}
```

Как я понял - вам нужно это.

UPD. Немного обновил. В случае неравномерного заполнения столбца (если в начале может оказаться null, а только потом значения).

```
bool SetString(string[,] array, string str, int index)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
      if (array[i,index] != null)
         if (array[i,index] == str)
            return false;

   for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
      if (array[i,index] == null)
      {
         array[i,index] = str;
         return true;
      }

   return false;
}
```

Comment: Вы посмотрите. Элемент массива приравняется str только в одном случае: если встретится null, после чего он выйдет из метода.